# Как сделать нестандартную ссылку?

Tags: css

Простите начинающего верстальщика, за возможно глупый вопрос, но прошу помощи.
Как можно сделать посредством css определённое состояние ссылки (сейчас неважно какое) с какими-то нестандартными настройками. Ну, то есть чтобы она становилась выделена не просто цветом или подчёркиванием, а чтобы к ней какая-то картинка появлялась или что-то наподобие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

слишком расплывчатая формулировка вопроса на мой взгляд, ибо, убирая подчёркивание, или изменяя цвет, Вы уже делаете нестандартную ссылку )) Ну а по поводу изображения при наведении просто меняйте фоновое изображение - `a:hover {background: url(images/image1.png) top left no-repeat;}`. приблизительно так.